# How to run two mock web services with different URL on the same port with citrus?

Tags: java, web-services, citrus-framework

I am investigating Citrus Framework in order to use it in test automation of my project. I want to run two web services, lets name it:

```
http://localhost:port/service1
http://localhosr:port/sercice2
```

and then call my SUT (system under test). SUT will synchronously call both of above mock services (service1 & service2) and return the answer.

I've managed to do it, BUT on different ports:

```
  <citrus-ws:server id="helloMockService1"
          port="${server.port1}"
          servlet-mapping-path="/service1"
          auto-start="true"
          timeout="10000"
          endpoint-adapter="genericResponseAdapter1" />

  <citrus-ws:server id="helloMockService2"
          port="${server.port2}"
          servlet-mapping-path="/service2"
          auto-start="true"
          timeout="10000" />
```

I need it on the same port. I've also tried to write my custom DispatchingEndpointAdapter and somehow extract the context path from the request Message, but didn't succeed..

```
<citrus:dispatching-endpoint-adapter id="dispatchingEndpointAdapter"
         mapping-key-extractor="mappingKeyExtractor"
         mapping-strategy="mappingStrategy"/>

<bean id="mappingStrategy"
  class="com.consol.citrus.endpoint.adapter.mapping.SimpleMappingStrategy">
    <property name="adapterMappings">
      <map>
          <entry key="service1" value-ref="genericResponseAdapter1"/>
          <entry key="service2" value-ref="genericResponseAdapter2"/>
      </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mappingKeyExtractor"
  class="com.mycompany.citrus.CustomExtractor">

</bean>
```

I cant find URL in request parameter of type com.citrus.message.Message..

```
package com.mycompany.citrus;

import com.consol.citrus.endpoint.adapter.mapping.MappingKeyExtractor;
import com.consol.citrus.message.Message;

public class CustomExtractor implements MappingKeyExtractor{

    @Override
    public String extractMappingKey(Message request) {

        // ther is no URL information in Message object!!!!!!!!!!!!
        return "service1";
    }

}
```

How do you run two mock services in Citrus Framework on the same port? I want to differentiate them by URL, not a payload itself... (by peyload it would be easy using above custom MappingKeyExtractor, since Message object contains payload)

Please help! I cant belive that Citrus Framework could be so badly designed that missed such a basic test requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Remove the *servlet-mapping-path* setting and use this mapping key extractor:

```
<bean id="mappingKeyExtractor" class="com.consol.citrus.endpoint.adapter.mapping.HeaderMappingKeyExtractor">
    <property name="headerName" value="#{T(com.consol.citrus.http.message.HttpMessageHeaders).HTTP_REQUEST_URI}"/>
</bean>
```

That will map incoming requests based on the request path. So you can add mappings with the keys **/service1** and **/service2** in the simple mapping strategy.